Record the content of an environment as a property
I came up with this question since I saw copy and reuse the content of an environment and thought that this might be solved using ltproperties.
I want to record the content of an environment as a property, here's my attempt which works well:
\documentclass{article}

% The first argument is a label name
\NewDocumentEnvironment{recording}{m +b}{
    \label{#1}
    \NewProperty{prop_name_#1}{now}{}{#2}
    \RecordProperties{prop_label_#1}{prop_name_#1}
    #2
}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{recording}{rec1}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
\end{recording}

\RefProperty{prop_label_rec1}{prop_name_rec1}

\end{document}

I had to put \NewProperty inside my environment to record the argument #2. As a result, a new property is defined every time when the environment is used.
Intuitively, this might be time and memory consuming (is it?). Is there a more elegant way to implement this?
Ideally, I suppose it may be like:
\NewProperty{record}{now}{}{#2}   % \NewProperty outside environment, ERROR
\NewDocumentEnvironment{recording}{m +b} {
    \label{#1}
    \RecordProperties{prop_label_#1}{record}
    #2
}{}


I wouldn't use properties for this. properties are written to the aux, and it is normally not good to do this with arbitrary user input. They are meant to record rather simple values of counter etc. And I would certainly not define a new property everytime.

@UlrikeFischer Thank you for the suggestions, I'll use other approaches instead.

While keeping Ulrike's warning in mind, you can certainly do this with properties. You do not need to define a new property each time. Just define it once to store the content of some macro and redefine the macro each time you call \RecordProperties. Below I define a recording and expandrecording environment. The former stores the content exactly as it is, while the latter expands the content of the environment at the time you call it. Most document commands like \section will break in expandrecording, so it should only be used when you need something like the value of a counter. Also, be aware that these environments cannot contain unexpected catcodes, meaning no verbatim material, macro definitions, or TikZ matrices (the last one can be averted with ampersand replacement).
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\NemoEnvBody{}
\NewProperty{nemo_env_body}{now}{}{\NemoEnvBody}

% The first argument is a label name
\NewDocumentEnvironment{recording}{m +b}{%
  \renewcommand\NemoEnvBody{\unexpanded{\unexpanded{#2}}}%
  \RecordProperties{#1}{nemo_env_body}%
  #2}{}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{expandrecording}{m +b}{%
  \renewcommand\NemoEnvBody{#2}%
  \RecordProperties{#1}{nemo_env_body}%
  #2}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Unexpanded body}
\begin{recording}{rec1}
normal text

\thesection
\end{recording}

\section{Expanded body}
\begin{expandrecording}{rec2}
normal text

\thesection
\end{expandrecording}

\section{Now let's reference}
\RefProperty{rec1}{nemo_env_body}

\RefProperty{rec2}{nemo_env_body}

\end{document}


As you can see, the value of \thesection is the same as when it was stored with expandrecording but not with recording. This makes sense if you look at the corresponding lines in the aux file.
\new@label@record{rec1}{{nemo_env_body}{normal text \par \thesection }}
\new@label@record{rec2}{{nemo_env_body}{normal text \par 2}}

Also note the use of two \unexpanded in recording. This is because when a property is written to the aux, it fully expands the content twice: once with a \protected@edef, another with the usual \write.

Is there a document talking about l3 to 'LaTeX2e` concept migration?

@projetmbc I don't think so, but interface3 has several comments like that in the "TeXhackers note" bits

In fact, there's https://www.latex-project.org/news/latex2e-news/ that I usually read via the TUGboat issues. The LaTeX2e News Issue 38 talks about properties... Mea culpa maxima!
